# Groovy Process executing

Tags: groovy

The following command works fine when used on a terminal

// Terminal

```
mysql -h localhost -u root my_database -e "select count(*) from page;"
```

But when used in a groovy script (via groovyconsole) it fails to execute. Instead the mysql usage options are printed, as if some unknown command was passed to mysql.

// Groovy Console

```
def p1 = 'mysql -h localhost -u root my_database -e "select count(*) from page;"'.execute()
p1.text
```

Any one know what's up with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why it's falling over, my guess is it is the way mysql is handling the select call in quotes...

As a workaround, this works:

```
[ 'mysql', 
  '-h', 'localhost',
  '-u', 'root',
  'my_database',
  '-e', 'select count(*) from page' ].execute().text
```

A nicer way of handling the output is to consume it (rather than use `text`) as this should alleviate any blocking issues should your buffers fill up....

Something like:

```
String output = new StringWriter().with { writer ->
  [ 
    'mysql', 
    '-h', 'localhost',
    '-u', 'root',
    'my_database',
    '-e', 'select count(*) from page'
  ].execute().with { proc ->
    consumeProcessOutput( writer, writer )
    waitFor()
  }
  writer.toString() 
}

println output
```

#### Edit:

Of course, you can always just use JDBC:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.21')
import groovy.sql.Sql

def rowcount = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database', 'root', '', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' ).with { sql ->
  def count = sql.firstRow( 'select count(*) from page' )[ 0 ]
  sql.close()
  count
}

println rowcount
```

#### Explanation

If you write a shell script like this (and save it as `/tmp/run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
do
  echo "$var"
done
```

Then, when you run:

```
println( '/tmp/run.sh "select count(*) from page"'.execute().text )
```

[groovy calls](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.java#L509) the simple form of [`Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29), and it prints out:

```
"select
count(*)
from
page;"
```

As you can see, the parameters get all messed up, as it separates the `select` bit into words.

When you instead call:

```
println( [ '/tmp/run.sh', '"select count(*) from page"' ].execute().text )
```

It prints out:

```
"select count(*) from page"
```

As [groovy calls](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.java#L569) the [`String[]` form of `Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) so java doesn't have to guess what the different parameters are, so keeps the `select` all in one parameter.

Hope this explains it :-)

Comment: Thanks, got it working. I don't really understand why the array approach works however?

Comment: @C0deAttack Added an explanation to my answer...hope it explains it!